# Two separate UITableViews in two separate controller, loading the same data

Tags: iphone, uitableview, sdk, nsmutablearray, plist

***first .h***

```
@interface PersonnelViewController : UIViewController 
    <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{

    NSMutableArray *personnelData;
    IBOutlet UITextField *tableCellText;
    IBOutlet UITableView *personTableView;
    IBOutlet UINavigationItem *navItem;

} 

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *personnelData;

-(IBAction)addRowToTableView;
-(IBAction)editTable;
-(NSString *)personDataFilePath;
-(IBAction)endText;



-(IBAction)done;
```

***first .m***

```
@implementation PersonnelViewController

@synthesize personnelData;

-(IBAction)done{    
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSArray *archivedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[self personDataFilePath]];
        if (archivedArray == nil) {

        personnelData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];                

    } else {
        personnelData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:archivedArray];
        }

}


- (IBAction)addRowToTableView {
    [personnelData addObject:tableCellText.text];



    [self personDataFilePath];
    [personTableView reloadData];       

}


- (IBAction)editTable {

    UIBarButtonItem *leftItem;

    [personTableView setEditing:!personTableView.editing animated:YES];

    if (personTableView.editing) {

    leftItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(editTable)];

    } else {

    leftItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(editTable)];


}

    navItem.rightBarButtonItem = leftItem;
    [self personDataFilePath];
    [personTableView reloadData];
}


- (IBAction)endText {

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [personnelData count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] autorelease];


}

    cell.textLabel.text = [personnelData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;

}

- (NSString *)personDataFilePath {

        NSString *personDataFilePath;
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        personDataFilePath = [[documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"applicationData.plist"] retain];
        return personDataFilePath;

}


- (void)saveData1 {

        [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:[personnelData copy]  toFile:[self personDataFilePath]];

}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        [personnelData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

}


- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        return YES;
}

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath
toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
    NSString *item = [[personnelData objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row] retain];
    [personnelData removeObject:item];
    [personnelData insertObject:item atIndex:toIndexPath.row];
    [item release];
}

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {


    }

    - (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

***Second .h***

```
@interface ApparatusViewController : UIViewController 
<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

NSMutableArray *apparatusData;
IBOutlet UITextField *tableCellText;
IBOutlet UITableView *mainTableView;
IBOutlet UINavigationItem *navItem;

} 

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *apparatusData;

-(IBAction)addRowToTableView;
-(IBAction)editTable;
-(NSString *)apparatusDataFilePath;
-(IBAction)endText;



-(IBAction)done;
@end
```

***Second .m***

```
@implementation ApparatusViewController

@synthesize apparatusData;

-(IBAction)done{    
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSArray *arichvedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[self apparatusDataFilePath]];
    if (arichvedArray == nil) {

        apparatusData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];                

    } else {
        apparatusData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:arichvedArray];
    }

}


- (IBAction)addRowToTableView {
    [apparatusData addObject:tableCellText.text];



    [self apparatusDataFilePath];
    [mainTableView reloadData]; 


}


- (IBAction)editTable {

    UIBarButtonItem *leftItem;

    [mainTableView setEditing:!mainTableView.editing animated:YES];

    if (mainTableView.editing) {

        leftItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(editTable)];

    } else {

        leftItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(editTable)];


    }

    navItem.rightBarButtonItem = leftItem;
    [self apparatusDataFilePath];
    [mainTableView reloadData];
}


- (IBAction)endText {

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [apparatusData count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] autorelease];


    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [apparatusData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;

}

- (NSString *)apparatusDataFilePath {

    NSString *apparatusDataFilePath;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    apparatusDataFilePath = [[documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"applicationData.plist"] retain];
    return apparatusDataFilePath;

}

- (void)saveData {

    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:[apparatusData copy]  toFile:[self apparatusDataFilePath]];

}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [apparatusData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];


}


- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath
toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
    NSString *item = [[apparatusData objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row] retain];
    [apparatusData removeObject:item];
    [apparatusData insertObject:item atIndex:toIndexPath.row];
    [item release];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}



@end
```

The data seems to be loading the same data into each table. How do I fix this.

Comment: You are loading the same data into array in both the controller thats why its happening .In the first controller you are filling array personnelData which contains same data as the array(apparatusData ) in second controller ,so its showing the same data in both tableview in different controllrs just load proper values in array you will get your output.

Answer (score 1):

You are loading "applicationData.plist" in both views!

Comment: If i change the name of applicationData.plist, the app crashes.

Comment: I have changed the names to applicationDataOne.plist and applicationDataTwo.plist. Seems to work, until I kill the app, my data is no longer there. It's like its not saying the data to the plist file anymore.

Comment: I fixed it, I was not using the saveData. I get an caution of method saveData not found, so it returns a type id. Is there something I need to add in the header file for the void statement (saveData)?